# How to properly use 'didInsertElement' in my case?

Tags: ember.js, components

I have the following component code (actual content omitted):

```
App.DataTableComponent = Ember.Component.extend({    
    test: function(){
        ...
    }.property('data')
});
```

I don't want the test to be available until the component is inserted, but I also have data passed into it. If I didn't have the data inserted, instead of .property('data'), I would just go .on('didInsertElement'). What about if both need to take place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 1st Approach

Return a value only when the component has been inserted:

```
App.DataTableComponent = Ember.Component.extend({    
  onInsert: function() {
    this.set('isInserted', true);
  }.on('didInsertElement'),

  test: function(){
    if (this.get('isInserted')) {
      // compute the test property here
      var someValue = this.get('data') + 5;
      return someValue;
    }
  }.property('data', 'isInserted')
});
```

---

### 2nd Approach

Define the computed property after the component was inserted:

```
App.DataTableComponent = Ember.Component.extend({    
  onInsert: function() {
    Ember.defineProperty(this, 'test',
       Ember.computed(this.testComputer).property('data')
    );
  }.on('didInsertElement'),

  testComputer: function(){
    // compute the test property here
    var someValue = this.get('data') + 5;
    return someValue;
  }
});
```

Comment: Ah, I tried to chain it after the property, like .property(...).on('didInsertElement'). Guess I was too naive. Thanks!